# Why using a pointer of this as default parameter to a function not allowed?

Tags: c++, default-value

I was just writing an inorder function to my Binary tree and I have encountered this difficulty.

```
class BinaryTree
{
private:
     struct Node* o_root;
public:
BinaryTree()
    {
              o_root = new Node();    
        o_root->data = 0;
        o_root->left = NULL;
        o_root->right = NULL;

    }
    void inorder(Node*root = o_root);//Invalid

};


void BinaryTree::inorder(Node* root = o_root)//Invalid
    {
         if(root==NULL)
         {
             return;
         }
         inorder(root->left);

         cout<< root -> data;

         inorder(root->right);

    }
```

I get an error : a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

if I turn the root node static this works.

Why should this be so ? If i have two binary trees I would want the specific root of the object, not a static member. I tried using a this operator but that gives me another error which basically says that use of this operator not allowed in default parameter.

Can anyone explain why this is not working and why has C++ denied use of this operator as default arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `this` isn't defined nor does it exist, when the method is actually called (imagine the resulting code). Same is true for actual member variables (without the pointer to the data there's no way to access the data either).

To elaborate this a bit more, it would also result in weird constructs that aren't really defined, like the following (remember that `o_root` is even private!):

```
sometree->inorder();
// ...would essentially be the same as...
sometree->inorder(sometree->o_root);
```

How about just overloading `inorder()`, removing the default parameter?

Basically use the following:

```
void BinaryTree::inorder(void)
{
    inorder(o_root);
}

void BinaryTree::inorder(Node* root)
{
    // your code as-is
}
```

Comment: Or as it's written, you could make `inorder` a function of `Node` that does the actual work, and then have `void BinaryTree::inorder(void) { o_root->inorder());`. Instead of calling `mytree.inorder(some_root);`, users could just call `some_root->inorder();`

Comment: I agree on your solution . That will work. But I still do not understand what u mean and why it is not allowed. When i call. mytreeobject->inorder() , isnt the this pointer refering to mytreeobject? or are you saying that the this pointer is only valid in the function body , and is not defined in the arguments?

Comment: Correct (the pointer would refer to it on paper, but not at that moment "in code"; when preparing parameters you're still in your caller, where you're able to access public stuff only and `this` would refer to the caller - not the callee). `this` is only valid inside the body (and the initialization list). See Luchian's answer for an excerpt from the standard description.

Comment: Thanks Mario. I've got it now from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually narrow the problem down even further:

```
class A
{
   int x;
   void foo(int k = x);
};
```

This is because the standard says so.

You can overload the method, `foo()`, and call `foo(x)` inside.

From 8.3.6/9

> [...] A nonstatic member shall not be used in a default argument
>   expression, even if it is not evaluated, unless it appears as the
>   id-expression of a class member access expression (5.2.5) or unless it
>   is used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1) [...]

For insight, you can read the whole section 8.3.6

Comment: qoute: You'd have to access a's memory at runtime, get the current value of x and push it in the argument stack, which doesn't really make sense"   exactly, why doesnt it do that? because that is what i want it to do. Why prevent it from doing it ? what is the issue they are concerned of ?